Why is the -n option not working for my cp command?
When I typ
cp file1 file2

it works perfectly, but of course, it overwrites the second file.
When I tried using -n or --no-clobber, there was no error message, I simply cat the files or opened them in vim and there was no changes
I changed from Windows to Linux Mint a couple weeks ago and I don't know if I need a special configuration in /usr/bin/cp to allow such an option to work.
I want to copy the contents of a file into the last line of another.

So what exactly do you want to happen? What's the definition of "work"? Overwrite: no; No change: no; Me: wat?

--update=none-fail, maybe?

@TomYan I want to copy the contents of a file into the last line of another.

Should I use --update=none-fail as an option of the cp command?

I want to copy the contents of a file into the last line of another That's not what you do with cp. The most common ways to append a file to another are cat a >> b and cat a | tee -a b.

. _.
Thank you very much. I get it now.

Please [edit] your question and clarify what you need. If you want to append the files to each other, that is a very different thing.

The copy command, cp copies a file to another destination, potentially overwriting ("clobbering") the destination if it already exists. From your description, this isn't what you want.
Instead look at the cat command, which reads a file and writes it out again. Not so useful by itself, but coupled with the shell's redirection operators > (output to) and >> (append to), is exactly what you need
cat file1 >> file2

Here, we read the contents of file1 and append it to file2.
Note that the shell applies the redirections before running the command, so cat x > x will truncate x ready to receive data before the cat x runs, leaving x empty

> effectively "clobbers"; only >> is exactly what you need indirection Also I think you mean "redirection"?

The reason is that you misinterpreted the use of cp command.
cp is a standard command in Linux that is not used to copy contents of a file to some other file but to copy a file itself and paste/write it to somewhere with a name.
Generally cp is intended when you either want to copy a file itself into another directory with the same/different filename, or copy the file itself in the same directory with some other filename.
But from your question I see that you actually want to copy contents of a file into some other file. Also you don't want to overwrite the file but to append the contents.
Then the best way is to use I/O redirection.
If you don't know about I/O redirection in bash I am leaving a quick go through for you with examples.
I/O Redirection
Input Redirection
grep something < file.txt

Output Redirection

Will write and completely overwrite(if already has some text) the file.

cat file.txt > file2.txt


Doesn't completely overwrite the file. Just appends the content at the end.

cat file.txt >> file2.txt


I want to copy the contents of a file into the last line of another.

So what you want to do should be done in this way -
cat file1 >> file2

